# Como configurar un chat con sockets de una pc a otra pc en distintas redes

Tags: java, socket

Tengo un programa de chat en JAVA funcionando perfectamente pero en la misma red yo quiero hacer que el chat funcione pero por ejemplo un compañero en su casa y yo en la mía, ya investigué pero no encuentro nada al respecto, alguien sabe como configurarlo?

Este es el codigo para servidor

```
ServerSocket servidor = null;
Socket socket = null;
BufferedReader lector = null;
PrintWriter escritor = null;
String usuario = "Default";
int port = 9000;
ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("/src/imagen/fondo.jpg");
public Servidor() {
    Thread principal = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                servidor = new ServerSocket(port);
                while (true) {
                    socket = servidor.accept();
                    leer();
                    escribir();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error " + ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Y este es para el cliente

```
ServerSocket servidor = null;
Socket socket = null;
BufferedReader lector = null;
PrintWriter escritor = null;
String usuario = "Default";
int port = 9000;
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/src/imagen/fondo.jpg");

public Clientee() {
    Thread principal = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                leer();
                escribir();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error " + ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: No se puede sin un servidor que no sea local fin de la triste historia :c, para hacerlo debes pagar por un servidor compatible con lo que sea que uses de servicio como socket (por ejemplo nodejs) y ejecutar el servicio desde el servidor y configurar tu socket para hacer listen al servidor, de esa manera tanto tu como esa persona pueden conectarse al mismo servidor estando en redes diferentes. pero con una computadora normal y no un servidor, hasta donde se tristemente es imposible o muy complicado...

Comment: Chale, nimodo, gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer que tu máquina sea el host y ejecutar el servidor ahí mismo. Deberás de pasar a tu amigo la ip pública (ver [Cuál es mi IP](https://www.cual-es-mi-ip.net/)) y el puerto del servidor. Pero para que el cliente se puede conectar con tu máquina, necesitarás abrir los puertos y en varias ocasiones se necesita desactivar el firewall. De este modo, ambos podrán estar conectados hacia un servidor en diferentes redes. En este vídeo muestran como [abrir los puertos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9ov62Wi44E). Bueno, es sobre SA-MP, pero te servirá como ejemplo..

Comment: Por cierto, una vez que cierres el programa servidor, quedarán incomunicados. Si quieres que eso no pase, necesitarás conseguir un host (de pago obviamente) en la cual pueda tener el servidor prendido las 24/7.

Answer (score 2):

Alguna vez me tocó hacer algo similar, para empezar es imposile conectar dos computadoras que no estén en la misma subred, así que debes de hacer algunas cosas un poco peligrosas.

Para empezar, debes configurar tus puertos y tu módem para que puedas comunicarte fuera de tu red local con otros.

Posteriormente debes crear una VPN (Red privada Virtual).

Para ello existe mucho software gratuito y de paga, personalmente usaría algo como [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/) que es la forma en que muchos jugadores hacen partidas con usuarios de otras partes del mundo usando las opciones de configuración de red local de su videojuego favorito (Yo alguna vez lo hice con un Age of Empires, con Starcraft y GTA pero fue hace como 10 años).

Y bueno, si tienes presupuesto y te gusta la aventura, te recomendaría probar [google-cloud-platform](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform), usar dos imagenes de linux en compute engine, una para cliente y otra para servidor, elegir al momento de crear las impagenes abrir puertos para otro protocolo (SSL creo que sería lo apropiado en tu caso).
GCP te permite crear una VPC  mediante sus asistente para acceder entre tus instancias mediante su nombre de instancia y no su ip.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes la manera facil como te comentaban adquirir un software o servicio que te permita hacer lo que deseas (que es la manera mas recomendada).

O montarte un servidor desde 0 (si tienes fedora es mas facil) pero igual tienes que tener intervencion del proovedor de servicios ya que algunas compañia limitan la creacion de dns personalizados y la apertura de puertos para la comunicacion exterior.
Pero si es asi te dare los siguientes pasos.
Solo lo he hecho en linux ya que en windows sinceramente no se que procedimientos se hagan.

peer to peer

Primero que nada instalar un fireball que controle las conexiones que aceden a su equipo (esto si es una version de nucleo anterior a 2 años si no omita este paso ya que en versiones recientes del sistemas linux ya viene incorporado el cortafuegos ufw).

Despues tienes que crear (o usar los sockets que viene por defecto en el sistema) junto al protocolo que le vas a asignar ya sea UDP, TCP (para mas informacion investigar el funcionamiento "ss" en linux).

Despues vas a un buscador(duckduckgo, google, bing o el de tu preferencia) y busca tu ip publica.

Despues configuras el cortafuegos de manera de que solo permita la entrada de la ip publica con la que tendras conexion junto con el puerto y el tipo de protocolo que va hacer dicha conexion(UDP, TCP).
y por ultimo configuras tu aplicacion que envie la solicitud a la ip publica y puerto designado con la que deseas tener comunicacion.

La otra opcion es crear un DNS personalizado para que puedan llegar los datos al lugar designado, para esto necesitas saber si tu proovedor de servicios tiene la opcion habilitadas en el router y si este soporta la carga tambien si tiene la opcion de habilitar puertos externos (por lo regular en mexico con el proovedor de "M" no tiene la opcion habilitada es necesario hacer una llamada para que te habiliten esas opciones esto sin costo alguno es dependiendo el proovedor de servicios de internet).
Ya teniendo el DNS y habilitado el puerto es mas facil monter un servidor sin tener mas intermediarios.
No pongo la explicacion con comando ya que cada distribucion de linux lo manejan de diferente manera pero los pasos que tiene similares son estos.
Con esto ya tienes un punto de partida para que puedas investigar mas si quieres hacerlo por ti solo.